Github Pages - Some Images Not Showing. The Other Images Are Displaying fine
I am new to Github Pages. I just finished some webpages and upload to my Github Pages.
Most webpages have about 25 images. I use relative path to display the images:
src="images/mypic.jpg"
However some images (about 5) are not display. The other images are displaying fine.
What may be the problem?
Thanks and best regards
Alex
